# How to get current webpage's CSS stylesheets with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've found this extension on the Chrome Web Store named CSS Used

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-used/cdopjfddjlonogibjahpnmjpoangjfff

With that extension , I can see the original style of the elements inside the page. (not the computed style)

I'm building an extension that requires getting the original styles of the webpage.

Is there a way that I can get the original CSS stylesheets with Chrome Extensions? Thank you very much!

Comment: As you can see in the code of that extension it simply downloads all CSS files referenced in `link` elements, parses the CSS and finds the matched rules. I suggest considering chrome.debugger API and its [CSS.getMatchedStylesForNode](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CSS/#method-getMatchedStylesForNode). Anyway, both approaches are quite complicated, so good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer man :) Appreciate it!

Comment: You have already identified an extension which does what you want. So, look at the code for the extension and see how they did it. The extension [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) may make it more convenient to do so.